# Converting ISO-8859-1 to utf-8 (øæå)

Tags: python, csv, unicode, latin1

I have a txt document containing letters ('øæå') and i want this script to recognize this letters and properly write them to the csv-file.

```
with codecs.open('transaksjonliste.txt', 'r', 'ISO-8859-1') as file:
    for line in file:

        line = file.readline() 
        lineS = line.encode('ISO-8859-1', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
        splitTab = lineS.split(';')

        for s in splitTab:
            newS = s[1:-1]

        date = splitTab[0].replace('.', '/')
        insertList = [date,]
        out.writerow(date)
```

Gives:

```
  File "Q:\DropBox\Development\Scripts\tes2.py", line 17, in <module>
    lineS = line.encode('ISO-8859-1', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 14: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Why are you both looping *and* calling `readline()`? Why the encode to Latin-1 then decode from UTF-8? Your data is not wrongly encoded, that strange dance is what causes your exception.

Comment: You are also ignoring `insertList` and did not tell us what `out` is; is that a `csv.writer()` object?

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance. Not aware of not needing to call readline(). @MartijnPieters insertList was a work in progress, but should not be the problem here. And yes the out is a csv.writer() object. Thanks for the headsup

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with codecs.open('transaksjonliste.txt', 'r', 'ISO-8859-1') as file:
    for line in file:

        line = file.readline() 
        lineS = line.encode('ISO-8859-1', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
        splitTab = lineS.split(';')
```

Remove `line = file.readline()` , you are already iterating(reading) through the lines with the `for line in file` construct.

```
lineS = line.encode('ISO-8859-1', 'ignore').decode('utf-8')
```

wouldn't be what you want, as this encodes to ISO-8859-1 and then tries to decode the ISO-8859-1 as if it was UTF-8. If you want to convert 'ISO-8859-1' to UTF-8, you'd normally want to do

```
 lineS = line.decode('ISO-8859-1', 'ignore').encode('utf-8')
```

However you've already converted the data from 'ISO-8859-1' (to unicode) in the codecs.open() expression. So you just need to do

```
  lineS = = line.encode('utf-8')
```